# Why grub-mkrescue doesn't accept the "--core-compress=xz" option?

Tags: debian, grub2

Is lack some package or lack some other options? or just a bug of grub-mkresuce? **Is some example** for the `--core-compress=` option?

```
$ grub-mkrescue --core-compress=xz --compress=xz -o grub.iso ./iso
grub-mkrescue: --core-compress: (PROGRAM ERROR) Option should have been recognized!?
Try 'grub-mkrescue --help' or 'grub-mkrescue --usage' for more information.
```

Comment: You don't have much of a question in this Question.  The current answer seems to be "that's right, it didn't seem to accept that option".  Perhaps the `xz` compression tool is not available?

Comment: But `grub-mkrescue --help`  explicit say it accept this "--core-compress=xz",and some error possible not a bug of `grub-mkrescue` self,that is lack some packge,for example `grub-pc-bin` and `xorriso`. and the `--compress=xz` option is work. @JeffSchaller

Comment: The question to ask at grub-devel@gnu.org. would be where GRUB_INSTALL_OPTIONS_INSTALL_CORE_COMPRESS is interpreted. Its help text neighbors are in util/grub-install-common.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that option --core-compress is declared but not implemented.
If you use an option unknown to grub-mkrescue and its helpers, then this
option gets forwarded to xorriso, which will complain if it does not
know the option either:

```
xorriso : FAILURE : -as mkisofs: Unrecognized option '--XYZ-compress=xz'
```

But you see a GRUB "PROGRAM ERROR", because include/grub/util/install.h has

```
  {"core-compress", GRUB_INSTALL_OPTIONS_INSTALL_CORE_COMPRESS,         \
      "xz|none|auto",                                           \
      0, N_("choose the compression to use for core image"), 2},        \
```

If you use the option, it gets translated into the number code
GRUB_INSTALL_OPTIONS_INSTALL_CORE_COMPRESS.
Now GRUB should somewhere have a piece of code which recognizes that
number, reads the argument "xz", and registers the user's wish.

It is done with "--compress=xz". install.h has:

```
  { "compress", GRUB_INSTALL_OPTIONS_INSTALL_COMPRESS,            \
    "no|xz|gz|lzo", 0,                            \
    N_("compress GRUB files [optional]"), 1 },                            \
```

and util/grub-install-common.c has:

```
    case GRUB_INSTALL_OPTIONS_INSTALL_COMPRESS:
      if (strcmp (arg, "no") == 0
      ...
      if (strcmp (arg, "gz") == 0)
      ...
      if (strcmp (arg, "xz") == 0)
```

But for GRUB_INSTALL_OPTIONS_INSTALL_CORE_COMPRESS, there is no such
code nowhere.

Comment: Meanwhile i made up a theory what might have gone wrong in 2013: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/grub-devel/2018-09/msg00018.html